Linq query to Linq lambda EF Core Join
I'm trying to do a Left Join in EF Core using Linq Lambda.
I found the code I needed that works in Linq query format, but I prefer to use Lambda over query.
public class PlayerWithOverride
{
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public PlayerOverride PlayerDataOverride{ get; set; }

}

var query = from b in ctx.Players
            join p in ctx.PlayerOverrides
            on b.PlayerId equals p.PlayerId into grouping
            from p in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty() where b.PlayerId == 2706
             select new PlayerWithOverride() { Player = b, PlayerDataOverride= p };

var res = query.FirstOrDefault(); // Correctly return a row even when there is no match in sub table. 


The above works correctly. It will return a player, and if there is a matching override in the PlayerOverrides table, it will add that to PlayerDataWithOverride, if not PlayerDataWithOverride will be null. So it's performing a Left Join.
var test = ctx.Players.Where(o => o.PlayerId == 2706).Join(
    ctx.PlayerOverrides.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    p => p.PlayerId,
    e => e.PlayerId,
    (p, e) => new PlayerWithOverride()
    {
        Player = p,
        PlayerDataOverride = e

     });

var pl = test.FirstOrDefault(); // null when both rows don't match


When trying to do the same thing in Lambda (above) it's performing a inner join, causing it to only return anything if there is a result from both tables.
What is the correct Lambda translation for the query version?

Typically figured it out right after posting...
var query2 = ctx.Players
             .Where(b => b.PlayerId ==2706)
             .GroupJoin(ctx.PlayerOverrides,
                  b => b.PlayerId,
                  p => p.PlayerId,
                  (b, grouping) => new { b, grouping })
               .SelectMany(
                   g => g.grouping.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                   (x, p) => 
                   new PlayerWithOverride 
                   {
                       Player = x.b, PlayerDataOverride = p
                   });


ChatGPT can do that with ease, but I prefer to stick with Query syntax when I need joins to several tables. C# compiler hides these ugly transparent classes and transformations.
